# How to use pre_save methods in rest_framework serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know this is a noob question about `DRF`. I use latest version of `Django` and `DRF`.  In my Django , I create slugs in a method using `pre_save signals.`

```
    def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
      slug = slugify(instance.title)
      if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
      qs = Article.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
      exists = qs.exists()
      if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug = new_slug)
      return slug



@receiver(pre_save, sender = Article)
def pre_save_article_receiver(sender, instance, raw, using, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
      instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_article_receiver, sender=Article)
```

Then I can manage to write my views and serializers using DRF

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from yogavidya.apps.articles.models import Article

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = [
      "title",
      "user",
      "content",
      "excerpt",
    ]
```

--views.py--

```
app_name = 'articles'
class ArticleListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
                  lookup_field = 'pk'
                  serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
                  queryset = Article.objects.all()

                  def list(self, request):
                        # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
                        queryset = self.get_queryset()
                        serializer = ArticleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                        print(serializer.data)
                        return Response(serializer.data)
                  def get_queryset(self):
                    return Article.objects.all()

                  def get_object(self):
                    pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
                    return Article.objects.get(pk=pk)

                  def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
                """
                API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
                """
                queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-title')
                serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

When I post my form I get `name 'create_slug' is not defined`. Where is best place to override my save method and updates? can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess that is indentation problem. you need to put `create_slug` method outside your model.

Comment: @SumeetKumar ... `create_slug` works when I use in Django , it does not cause problems in my models. it is only problem in api. Where do i need to get it?

Comment: @SumeetKumar ... yes you were right. I have got `create_slug` method out , it works. Do you want to write an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Posted it as answer. :) glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess error is due to the wrong indentation of `def create_slug`

```
Class Xyz:
    ...
    ...

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
      slug = slugify(instance.title)
      if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
      qs = Article.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
      exists = qs.exists()
      if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug = new_slug)
      return slug
```

It is not a class function, so it should be outside class.